# Разрешить Wireguard серверу только трафик с определенных портов

Tags: linux, unix, wireguard

Я хочу заставить свой Wireguard обрабатывать только тот трафик, что имеет определенный протокол (udp) и определенные порты. Есть ли способы это сделать?